# Tensorflow-lite large model run faster on Kirin 970 CPU than it's GPU

Tags: android, tensorflow, mobile, tensorflow-lite

I'm testing tensorflow-lite benchmark on Kirin 970, and notice that the small model like mobilenet and squeezenet run faster on GPU than CPU and the large model like VGG-16 run faster on CPU. It's sort of weird. What are the causes of these phenomena?

Test using command:

```
./benchmark_model --graph=convert_tflite_model/vgg16.tflite  --num_threads=8 --warmup_runs=1 --num_runs=10 --use_gpu=true --run_delay=1
```

Here are my test results:

*"GPU default" means using default setting of GPU.*

*"GPU 767MHz" means setting GPU frequency to 767MHz(Max frequency of GPU on Kirin 970)*

[Table: models run time on CPU and GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe7Gu.png)

[Histogram: CPU time/GPU time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEV2h.png)

---

BTW, how to shut down Kirin 970 thermal throttling? It will reduce frequency just in few seconds during test because of overheating. Frequency reduction makes it harder to get solid test results.

Comment: The larger model require way more memory then the smaller ones. Swapping the memory in and out could be the reason why it is slow. Try comparing run-time of a small model on GPU and CPU. Regarding thermal throttling, are you sure you want to do it? It may overhead damaging other components. Try to keep your phone cool during testing with a fan pointed at it (or some other creative approach :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We are going to test the run time without considering memory swap time. It gonna be some work with TensorFlow-lite source code to modify its timer. (I'm not sure weather we can get it.) BTW, we are testing a development board not a phone. It's Hikey970. Though I am just slightly worried about it because it belong to the company,  what I want more is solid results :).

Comment: For the cooling, just place some fan on top of the board or if you want more sophisticated solution try buying a heat spreader which should decapitate heat off of the CPU/GPU allowing faster clock speeds.